# Install Cairo for PHP in Windows

Tags: php, cairo, pecl

I am using Windows 8 and XAMPP in my development system.

I want to install cairo extension. I see that, PECL cairo is the official Cairo binding. I couldn't find php*.dll

Can you help me with reference for installing Cairo in my Php+Windows system.

Also, is PECL-Cairo being actively developed, its last release was on 2012-04-21.